# Pandas => get index of first and last element by group

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, optimization

I have a dataframe with roughly 100M rows, (1.4Gb in memory)

Given the input:

```
df.head()

Out[1]:
     id    term     x
0     1     A       3
1     1     B       2
2     2     A       1
3     2     B       1
4     2     F       1
5     2     G       1
6     2     Z       1
7     3     K       1
8     3     M       1
9     3     N       1
10    3     Q       1
11    3     R       1
12    3     Z       1
13    4     F       1
```

I'd like to retrieve the index of the first row for each id.  Example:

```
Out[1]:
     id    first_idx
0     1    0       
1     2    2       
2     3    7      
2     4    13
```

My current approach is incredibly slow:

```
first_row = {}
last_id = None
first_row = None

#iterate over all rows
for idx,r in bow.iterrows():
    cid = r['id']
    if cid != last_id: #is this an ID we haven't seen before?
        first_row[cid] = idx
        last_id = cid
```

Any advice would be a huge help.

Comment: In general you should avoid iterating over the rows a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### I. For generic case

**Approach #1** With `np.unique` -

```
idx = np.unique(df.id.values, return_index=1)[1]
```

To get the last indices for each `ID`, simply use `flipped` version and subtract from dataframe's length -

```
len(df)-np.unique(df.id.values[::-1], return_index=1)[1]-1
```

#### II. For `id` col already being sorted

**Approach #2-A** We can use `slicing` for noticeable  performance boost, as we would be avoiding sorting -

```
a = df.id.values
idx = np.concatenate(([0],np.flatnonzero(a[1:] != a[:-1])+1))
```

**Approach #2-B** With `masking` (better for lots of id numbers)

```
a = df.id.values
mask = np.concatenate(([True],a[1:] != a[:-1]))
idx = np.flatnonzero(mask)
```

For the last index :

```
np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate((a[1:] != a[:-1],[True])))
```

**Approach #3** For sequential numbers, we can use `np.bincount` -

```
a = df.id.values
idx = np.bincount(a).cumsum()[:-1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [334]: df
Out[334]: 
    id term  x
0    1    A  3
1    1    B  2
2    2    A  1
3    2    B  1
4    2    F  1
5    2    G  1
6    2    Z  1
7    3    K  1
8    3    M  1
9    3    N  1
10   3    Q  1
11   3    R  1
12   3    Z  1
13   4    F  1

In [335]: idx = np.unique(df.id.values, return_index=1)[1]

In [336]: idx
Out[336]: array([ 0,  2,  7, 13])
```

If you need the output in a dataframe -

```
In [337]: a = df.id.values

In [338]: pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((a[idx], idx)), columns=[['id','first_idx']])
Out[338]: 
   id  first_idx
0   1          0
1   2          2
2   3          7
3   4         13
```

Comment: This is blazing fast.  I really need to learn how to use numpy for data manipulation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.index.to_series().groupby(df['id']).first().reset_index(name='x')
print (df)
   id   x
0   1   0
1   2   2
2   3   7
3   4  13
```

If want also last index values:

```
df = df.index.to_series().groupby(df['id']).agg(['first','last']).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  first  last
0   1      0     1
1   2      2     6
2   3      7    12
3   4     13    13
```

Comment: this one is the most efficient in memory use. The other answers were what I used before but those were not working with a big dataframe that occupies the max memory of machine.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness:

```
df.reset_index().groupby("id")["index"].first()
id
1     0
2     2
3     7
4    13
```

For `last`:

```
df.reset_index().groupby("id")["index"].last()
id
1     1
2     6
3    12
4    13
```

Timing:

```
df.drop_duplicates('id').reset_index()
1.64 ms ± 31.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

df.reset_index().groupby("id")["index"].first()
1.93 ms ± 8.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['x'].agg(lambda x: x.index[0])
7.96 ms ± 419 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

df.index.to_series().groupby(df['id']).first().reset_index(name='x')
3.11 ms ± 77.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: What about `df = df.index.to_series().groupby(df['id']).first().reset_index(name='x')` ?

Comment: For same output `df.index.to_series().groupby(df['id']).first()` ;)

Comment: @jezrael I am not making up figures )

Comment: I think timings are not same - first 1 return Series, last 2 DataFrame ;)

Comment: Can you test my method also ?

Comment: Note that the Numpy "generic solution" of the accepted answer is multiple times faster than Pandas’ solutions (at least for "small" dataframes).

Comment: @SkippyleGrandGourou Numpy is faster by definition. If you strive for speed don't touch Pandas ever.

Answer (score 3):

....`drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates('id').reset_index()
Out[564]: 
   index  id term  x
0      0   1    A  3
1      2   2    A  1
2      7   3    K  1
3     13   4    F  1
```

Comment: Added timing for yours. You are the winner so far )

Comment: Goodnight @Wen!